# Combined Array of object properties inside Object, Inside Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Given this array of objects:

```
[
    {"Code": 101, "Description": "Invoice"},
    {"Code": 102, "Description": "Credit"},
    {"Code": 103, "Description": "Credit"},
    {"Code": 111, "Description": "Invoice"},
    {"Code": 112, "Description": "Credit"},
    {"Code": 113, "Description": "Credit"},
    {"Code": 182, "Description": "Backup"}
]
```

I need to combine the objects that have matching `Description`s into one single object with an array of `Code`s, like so:

```
[
    {"Code": [101,111], "Description": "Invoice"},
    {"Code": [102,103,112,113], "Description": "Credit"},
    {"Code": [182], "Description": "Backup"}
]
```

I have tried with the `groupBy()` helper function below (the vanilla JS one) and it is not working because I get an `Object` with a single `undefined` property with the original array as it's value:

```
var groupBy = function (arr, criteria) {
    return arr.reduce(function (obj, item) {

        // Check if the criteria is a function to run on the item or a property of it
        var key = typeof criteria === 'function' ? criteria(item) : item[criteria];

        // If the key doesn't exist yet, create it
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            obj[key] = [];
        }

        // Push the value to the object
        obj[key].push(item);

        // Return the object to the next item in the loop
        return obj;

    }, {});
};

var array = [
    {"Code": 101, "Description": "Invoice"},
    {"Code": 102, "Description": "Credit"},
    {"Code": 103, "Description": "Credit"},
    {"Code": 111, "Description": "Invoice"},
    {"Code": 112, "Description": "Credit"},
    {"Code": 113, "Description": "Credit"},
    {"Code": 182, "Description": "Backup"}
];

var groupDescription = groupBy(array, array.forEach(document => document.Description));

console.log(groupDescription);
```

What would be the best way to achieve my expected output?

Comment: "the best way" - what are you looking for? does the current code not work?

Comment: Mods: this question was asked before by the OP where the original question was down-voted and closed as a dupe. However, the accepted answer on the dupe link does not answer the question...

Comment: Thank you @RobinMackenzie for the clarification!

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, it wasn't doing what I needed. Robin's Answer does, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output is an `Array`, but the `reduce` logic in your `groupBy` function takes an `Object` as it's initial value. It's not obvious why you want to run the `criteria` function for each item in the input array, as `Description` is a `String`, not an `Array`.

A simpler approach (may, or may not, be the best):

- get the unique set of `Description`s as an array
- iterate that array and for each `Description`, filter the original array and get the `Code`s

See below:

```js
var arr = [
  {"Code": 101, "Description": "Invoice"},
  {"Code": 102, "Description": "Credit"},
  {"Code": 103, "Description": "Credit"},
  {"Code": 111, "Description": "Invoice"},
  {"Code": 112, "Description": "Credit"},
  {"Code": 113, "Description": "Credit"},
  {"Code": 182, "Description": "Backup"}
];

// expected output
//[
//  {"Code": [101,111], "Description": "Invoice"},
//  {"Code": [102,103,112,113], "Description": "Credit"},
//  {"Code": [182], "Description": "Backup"}
//]

var grouped = Array
  .from(new Set(arr.map(o => o.Description))) // get unique Descriptions as array
  .map(d => { // iterate that array
    return {
      "Code": arr
        .filter(o => o.Description === d) 
        .map(o => o.Code), // return just the Code for original array items matching this unique Description
      "Description": d  // the Description
    }
  });
  
console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Amazing! Now this works exactly as I need it. Thanks a lot, Robin. And thanks for clarifying to the Mods that this is a different kind of question.